# TestingngZone runOutsideAngular

Tags: angular, jasmine

In our component we have to run a method outside of angular zone. We use that code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.layoutService.bindScroll();
    });
}
```

We struggle to test this small snippet.

`layoutService` is mocked using `createSpyObj('layoutService, ['bindSroll'])`.

For the ngZone part, We can create a `spyObj` containing `runOutsideAngular` method of `ngZone` and provide it.

But doing so, what to place in the `ngZone.runOutsideAngukar.and.callFake()` method to be able to test if onInit, we get the `bindSroll` method called, within `runOutsideAngular`.

How to test both behaviors:

- Call of `runOutsideAngular` at init
- Call of the `bindScroll` within runOutsideAngular

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking [NgZone.assertNotInAngularZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#assertNotInAngularZone) inside `bindScroll` will help.